# VB.NET constructors in derived classes

Tags: vb.net, constructor, derived-class, base-class

I have a base class that I use with reflection to fill the fields of the derived classes, reading from the database.

```
Public MustInherit Class DaoBase : Implements IEquatable(Of DaoBase)

        Sub New()
               ' Empty, hate to have it
        End Sub

        Sub New(reader As DbDataReader)
              '  Reads the DB and fills the instance fields
        End Sub

        '  More stuff...
End Class
```

The derived classes usually have a non-default constructor to set its fields:

```
Public Class Customer
        Inherits DaoBase

        Public Sub New(
            id As Integer,
            description As String)

            Me.id = id
            Me.description = description 
        End Sub

End Class
```

Questions:

1) I don't like to have the empty constructor in the base class. It sits there unused and could create an object in an incorrect state. If I remove it, then the compiler gives an error because, missing the default constructor, the derived class constructor should call the only-one base class constructor.

2) I can't do `new Customer(myReader)` because that constructor is not in the derived class, even if it's in the base class. I have to explicitly declare it, which I don't like.

```
Public Class Customer
        Inherits DaoBase

        Public Sub New(
            id As Integer,
            description As String)

            Me.id = id
            Me.description = description 
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(reader As DbDataReader)
            MyBase.New(reader)
        End Sub 

End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried something like Sub New(reader As DbDataReader = Nothing) and remove the empty constructor.

Comment: Have you tried something like Entity Framework instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @JohnSaunders When the wheel is too complex and buggy, reinventing it is good.

Comment: Sorry, EF: "complex and buggy"? You're joking, right? After six versions?

Answer (score 0):

If your base class is filling fields in the derived class, it sounds like you should be using an interface instead of what you're doing.

As for your questions, just because you don't like it doesn't make it wrong.  But as one comment said, if you change the second New to:

```
Sub New(Optional reader as DbDataReader = Nothing)
```

then you fulfill the requirement to have an empty constructor and you can have it do the right thing when no reader is given.